# Cross platform Canvas image zoom and crop make selection area fixed

Tags: javascript

Heavily inspired by [this](http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-image-crop-tool/), I have made a plugin that works in mobiles and desktops to crop an image

What I made is added touch support, added dynamic canvas size based on image dimensions and trying to add functionality of moving an image rather selection area like [here](http://codecanyon.net/item/image-crop/full_screen_preview/5348464). I wanted to buy this item but it has failed my test case in devices (I am sorry to mention here). So thought of customizing the first mentioned source.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RjdbT/10/).

my html is

```
<div class="container">
   <canvas id="panel" width="779" height="519"></canvas>
</div>

<input type="button" value="crop Selection" id="crop-image" />

<img id="croppedSelection" height="100px" width="100px" />
```

And calling it like

```
var Cropper = new CanvasCrop(document.getElementById('panel'), 'http://www.script- tutorials.com/demos/197/images/image.jpg');

$('#crop-image').on('click', function(){
   var src = Cropper.getBase64();
   $('#croppedSelection').attr('src', src);
});
```

My only problem is now, how can I keep the selection area on screen while image parent is being scrolled as [here](http://codecanyon.net/item/image-crop/full_screen_preview/5348464).

Thanks, help will be greatly appreciated.

Source code is huge to fit here, so added a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RjdbT/10/).. Thanks

**Edit**

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RjdbT/12/) fixed canvas height and width issue

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this code because I was bored.

Add this class above your code. you do not need the class if you only want one viewer on the page, you can put this all in a simple object. perhaps you need more:

```
function viewer (html_viewer)
    {
    this.html_viewer=html_viewer;
    Object.defineProperty (html_viewer,"viewer_instance",{writeable:false,configureable:false,enumerable:false,value:this});
    this.Selections=new Array ();
    html_viewer.addEventListener ("mousedown",this.startScrolling);
    html_viewer.addEventListener ("mouseup", this.endScrolling);
    html_viewer.addEventListener ("scroll",this.setSelectionPosition);
    }

viewer.prototype.startScrolling=function ()
    {
    var Selections=this.viewer_instance.Selections, Selection;
    var l=Selections.length;

    for (var i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
        Selection=Selections[i];
        Selection.startLeft=Selection.x;
        Selection.startTop=Selection.y;
        Selection.viewer_startScrollLeft=this.scrollLeft;
        Selection.viewer_startScrollTop=this.scrollTop;
        }
   }

viewer.prototype.setSelectionPosition=function ()
  {
  var Selections=this.viewer_instance.Selections, Selection;
  var l=Selections.length;
  for (var i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
    Selection=Selections[i];
    Selection.x=this.scrollLeft-Selection.viewer_startScrollLeft+Selection.startLeft;
    Selection.y=this.scrollTop-Selection.viewer_startScrollTop+Selection.startTop;
    }

  this.viewer_instance.drawScene ();
  }

 viewer.prototype.endScrolling=function ()
   {
   var Selections=this.viewer_instance.Selections, Selection;
   var l=Selections.length;

   for (var i=0;i<l;i++)
     {
     Selection=Selections[i];
     Selection.startLeft=null;
     Selection.startTop=null;
     Selection.viewer_startScrollLeft=null;
     Selection.viewer_startScrollTop=null;
     }
   }

 viewer.prototype.addSelection=function (Selection)
    {
    Selection.startLeft=null;
    Selection.startTop=null;
    Selection.viewer_startScrollLeft=null;
    Selection.viewer_startScrollTop=null;
    Selection.viewerIndex=this.Selections.length;
    this.Selections.push (Selection);
    }

 viewer.prototype.removeSelection=function (viewerIndex)
    {
    var Selections=this.Selections, l=Selections.length, i;
    Selection=Selections[viewerIndex];
    delete Selection.startLeft;
    delete Selection.startTop;
    delete Selection.viewer_startScrollLeft;
    delete Selection.viewer_startScrollTop;
    delete Selection.viewerIndex;

  for (i=viewerIndex+1;i<l;i++)
    Selections[i].viewerIndex=i-1;  

  Selections.splice (viewerIndex,1);
    }

var imageViewer= new viewer (document.getElementById("panel").parentNode);
```

After line 27 
    theSelection = new Selection(64, 64, 64, 64);

Add

```
imageViewer.addSelection (theSelection);
imageViewer.drawScene=drawScene;
```

That's all, if you have problems let me know.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I was waiting for an answer like anything. Could you please provide a fiddle or shall I try myself?

Comment: Could u please add a fiddle.

Comment: i have no account at fiddle, but its not hard to do, put the class in the big  scrollable window above var CanvasCrop = (function ()  and then add the two lines aft line 27 thats all

Comment: @ThorstenAtrner'Austria' I just updated the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/RjdbT/13/. I am facing problem only when I scroll to bottom, selection area is going beyond the parent. Could you please look into that. And you can update the code there itself

Comment: which browser i have no problems

Comment: Chrome, if I scroll it is by the default going to start position of the window, I mean parent DIV. Can we smoothen it to stay in old position and scroll only canvas image?

Comment: I mean to say, even by mistake if I touch the scroll it is going to start position.

Comment: hm i really dont know what you mean.. the parent div of the canvas is always on top left at the fiddle column. what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54313/discussion-between-thorsten-artner-austria-and-redv).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54345/discussion-between-redv-and-thorsten-artner-austria).

Comment: ill start working on a class called image cropper. i hope you are a little bit into advanced programming to understand the code, but i think so. I'll take your selection code if im allowed to, to reduce work. your job would be to integrate mobile events or touch events, because normally im developing hta in my freetime, i didnt develop something for mobile phone except a ginger bread designer. when do you need the whole stuff?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sure I can add mobile compatibility.

Comment: you can watch the progress on http://jsfiddle.net/ThorstenArtnerAustria/5qdDW/  .. in the moment you can scroll the image, i'll finsih now for today

Answer (score 2):

need further discussion how to implement image crop. do you want a selection inside the canvas or do you want to resize the complete imageCropper container and make a crop

```
// look at
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ThorstenArtnerAustria/5qdDW/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot... after completing selection I want to make a crop

Comment: Do you want a selection inside the canvas or do you want to simply resize the whole container to get smaller or bigger pictures?

Comment: I want to crop only selected area. I mean with aspect ratio.